# How can I import a .net core C# application into my .NET framework vb.net application

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, .net-core, ml.net

Basically, I intended to design a hospital management application as my final year project using vb.net, and along the line I wanted to be able to use predictive analytics with the app. This led me to finding out about Machine Learning .NET, but unfortunately, ML.NET and model builder is not compatible with vb.net.
I then decided to create the analytics module using C# and .NET core which works well for ML.NET, but now I have two separate apps. Is there a way for me to be able to import this analytics module into my vb.net app? I have read something about creating a class library but I neither know how to do this or import it into my vb.net app, anyone that can help me with this would be of great assistance.

Comment: Instead of creating a C# application project targeting .NET Core, you should have created a C# library project targeting .NET Framework. It's simply a different project template selected in the New Project dialogue. You can then add a reference in your VB application project to the C# project and away you go. The VB project then knows about all the public types declared in the C# project. References is how any project knows about types declared in any other assembly. You cannot reference between .NET Core and .NET Framework though. Copy your C# classes into the new project.

Comment: How chatty is the interface?  Set the C#/ML app up as a server and talk to it from the VB app (WCF, JSON/REST, whatever).  The other thing is that you might be able to get away by having the C# component being a .NET Standard library.

Comment: Not an answer, but how tied are you to the Framework? If you could upgrade your VB app to .NET5, then this would be a non-issue.

Comment: @NPras I can upgrade to .NET 5 without an issue, its basically one form that I need, could you put me through the process of porting that form into my VB app?

Comment: @PromiseOkoli Sounds like your project is likely to be quite straightforward. MS has a whole [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/) devoted to porting. Most relevant would be the section on Upgrade Assistant. More specifically the Windows Forms subsection. Feel free to open up a question if you run into any roadblocks when converting!